# Can seeded data use the HiLo sequence?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Please see the class below:

```
public class UndergraduateEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Undergraduate>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Barclaycard> undergraduateConfiguration)
        {
            undergraduateConfiguration.HasData(
               new Undergraduate(1, "Undergraduate")
               );
        }
    }
```

and the code below:

```
public class StudentEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CreditCard> studentConfiguration)
        {
            studentonfiguration.ToTable("Student", StudentContext.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
            studentConfiguration.HasKey(o => o.Id);
            studentConfiguration.Property(o => o.Id)
                .ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo("studentseq", StudentContext.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
           studentConfiguration.HasDiscriminator<string>("Type")
                .HasValue<Graduate>("Graduate")
                .HasValue<Vanquis>("Undergraduate");

        }
    }
```

Notice the Student ID field (in the Student table) uses a HiLo sequence.  However, in UndergraduateEntityTypeConfiguration I have to explicitly pass an ID number to the Undergraduate constructor to add the Undergraduate record to the Student table.

The code works as expected.  However, I am confused why I have to pass an ID (1) myself.  Is there a way of creating the Undergraduate record like this:

```
undergraduateConfiguration.HasData(
               new Undergraduate("Undergraduate")
               );
```

Note that this time no ID is passed to the constructor.  If I do this, then I see an error, which says: "The seed entity for entity type 'Undergraduate' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Id'".

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a specific requirement for EF Core data seeding with `HasData` (a.k.a [Model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)) coming from  the design of the feature.

It's not specific for HiLo sequence generated columns, but *all* auto generated columns (including the most used auto increment (identity) and database sequence generated columns). The explanation in the documentation is as follows (pay special attention to the first bullet):

> This type of seed data is managed by migrations and the script to update the data that's already in the database needs to be generated without connecting to the database. This imposes some restrictions:
>
> - The primary key value needs to be specified even if it's usually generated by the database. It will be used to detect data changes between migrations.
> - Previously seeded data will be removed if the primary key is changed in any way.

If it's a problem for you, consider switching to the [more traditional way of data seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#custom-initialization-logic).